# Replace an element in an array with a unique identifier

Tags: typescript

I have an array of `dailyEntries`. A DailyEntry has an unique identifier `id`. I get an external `dailyEntry` and want to replace the `dailyEntry` inside the array with the external one.

I do this with:

```
this.dailyEntries = this.dailyEntries.map(function (dailyEntry) {
  if (dailyEntry.id === externalEntry.id) {
    dailyEntry = externalEntry;
  }
  return dailyEntry;
});
```

Is there a better way to do it? That seems like a bit too much code for a simple replacement.

Edit:
I guess i can do the same thing in one line:

```
this.dailyEntries = this.dailyEntries.map(dailyEntry => dailyEntry.id === entry.id ? entry : dailyEntry);
```

But is there stil a better solution?

Comment: Do you know for sure that it exists in the array, or do you need to handle adding it if not (the code above isn't).

Comment: _"That seems like a bit too much code for a simple replacement"_ - The "replacement" is only one line. The rest tries to find the element you want to replace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript ES6/ES5 find in array and change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206125/javascript-es6-es5-find-in-array-and-change)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But is there stil a better solution?

Not really. The code can be more concise *(edit: you edited your question to say that as well)*:

```
this.dailyEntries = this.dailyEntries.map(dailyEntry => dailyEntry.id === externalEntry.id ? externalEntry : dailyEntry);
```

Or it's common to use `e` for the parameter in that kind of operation, since it's a very small function (`e` stands for "element"):

```
this.dailyEntries = this.dailyEntries.map(e => e.id === externalEntry.id ? externalEntry : e);
```

Another way is `findIndex`, but it doesn't seem as good as your `map` solution:

```
const index = this.dailyEntries.findIndex(({id}) => id === externalEntry.id);
this.dailyEntries[index] = externalEntry;
```

(That uses destructuring to pick out the `id` from the entry parameter to the `map` callback.)

The big difference between them is that the `map` solution creates a new array, but the `findIndex` solution updates the **existing** array (which has the advantage that it short-circuits when the entry is found; but the disadvantage that sometimes you want to treat objects [including arrays] as though they were immutable).

You could always give yourself a reusable function for this operation:

```
function replaceInArray(array, propName, newEntry) {
    return array.map(e => e[propName] === newEntry[propName] ? newEntry : e);
}
```

then

```
this.dailyEntries = replaceInArray(this.dailyEntries, "id", externalEntry);
```

---

All of the above assumes (like your current code) that the entry definitely exists in the array. If the entry may *not* be in the array, that makes `map` less attractive and suggests `findIndex` is the better way to go:

```
const index = this.dailyEntries.findIndex(({id}) => id === externalEntry.id);
if (index === -1) {
    this.dailyEntries.push(externalEntry);
} else {
    this.dailyEntries[index] = externalEntry;
}
```

---

Last but not least: If you're referring to the entry by its `id` in multiple places, an array may not be the right data structure (but it may well be, it depends on what else you're doing with it). For instance, you might keep these in a `Map` instead (or an object). Then replacing it (or adding it if not there) is **really** simple:

```
this.dailyEntries.set(externalEntry.id, externalEntry);
```

If you need an array of the entries (in the order in which they were added), you can get it from the iterable from the `Map`'s `values` method: `[...this.dailyEntries.values()]` (or just use the iterable directly, if you don't need an *array* per se).