# How to change values in array of objects with an onClick?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, array.prototype.map

I'm using react and trying to edit objects when a button is pressed. Currently, I have rendered 2 buttons on the page that display their correct values, but when the button is pressed I get "buttonUpgrades.map is not a function". The changeButtonData function can log the correct data but I cant seem to make any changes to the data.

From my understanding the reason this is sending an error is that buttonUpgrades is an object, but I don't know how to solve the issue.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
const UpgradeButton = () => {
    const [buttonUpgrades, updateButtonUpgrades] = useState([
    {
      id:0,
      name: "Upgrade one",
      cost: 5,
      amount: 0,
      damage: 1,
      damageGrowth: 1.1,
    },
    {
      id:1,
      name: "Upgrade two",
      cost: 6,
      amount: 0,
      damage: 2,
      damageGrowth: 1.2,
    },
  ]);

  const changeButtonData = (data) => {
    let {name,cost,damage} = data;
    updateButtonUpgrades(...buttonUpgrades, name="new name") // this wont let me change the value that has been assigned
    console.log(name) // this logs the name assigned to the button 
  }

  return(  
    buttonUpgrades.map((upgrade)=>
    <button key={upgrade.id}onClick={()=>changeButtonData(upgrade)}>
      <h1>Cost:{upgrade.name}</h1>
      <h1>Cost:{upgrade.cost}</h1>
      <h1>Damage:{upgrade.damage}</h1>
    </button>
    )
  )
}
export default UpgradeButton;
```

Edit: Solution incase anyone comes across this:

```
  const changeButtonData  = (data)=>{
    const {id,name,cost,amount,damage,damageGrowth} = data;
    updateButtonUpgrades(buttonUpgrades.map(buttonProps=>(buttonProps.id===id ? {...buttonProps,damage:damage * damageGrowth}:buttonProps)))
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your updateButtonUpgrades isn't set up properly.

```js
updateButtonUpgrades(...buttonUpgrades, name="new name")
```

is trying to map out the buttonUpgrades in the component's return, but you have it [spread with the ... syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in your updateButtonUpgrades function call, so all you're doing is [passing the items in the array to the function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#syntax) instead of adding an item to the array. **That is where you get the buttonUpgrades.map is not a function error from**. To fix that, it should be set up like this:

```js
updateButtonUpgrades([...buttonUpgrades, (name = "new name")])
```

with the spread syntax ***INSIDE*** of an array. But now, all you're doing is adding "new name" to the array, which looks like this:

```js
[
  {id: 0, name: "Upgrade one", cost: 5, amount: 0…},
  {id: 1, name: "Upgrade two", cost: 6, amount: 0…},
  "new name"
]
```

From here:

- If you want to add an object, you would do it like so:

```js
updateButtonUpgrades([...buttonUpgrades, { name: "new name", cost, damage }]);
```

- If you want to replace a value with a new value, you should check out [this answer to another Stack Overflow question on how to find and change an object in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206125/javascript-es6-es5-find-in-array-and-change/61304412#61304412)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to rewrite your onClick-callback-function: first create the new objects with the desired attributed, group them in an array and then update the react state with this new array.

EDIT: jharris711 gives a clean implementation of this concept, great work!